# 2d WebGL library and porting to IOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, webgl

I know this is a kind of multi-pronged question, but I'm about to embark on a WebGL 2D game, and in the future I would like to port it to IOS and android.
I've got a little OpenGL experience but I would rather use an established 2d WebGL Library from the start, so does anyone have any experience with these; and do you know what approach will be easiest to port to IOS/Android in the future?

I'm aware webGL isn't currently supported by IOS so perhaps the process of porting it will require re-writing all the non openGL code, which is why I'm wondering if any WebGL libraries were built with this in mind..

I'm also away IOS will probably in the future support WebGL so perhaps I should consider this a mute point and just assume that it will be supported before I'm ready to port anyway..

Any resources that might help me get started on the venture are also very welcome!

Thanks!

TLDR: **What's a good 2D WebGL library that will save me heartache in the long-run porting to other devices?**

Comment: How much time do you have till you will be porting?

Comment: It's a pet project, so... The rest of my life I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Easle JS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) (of the CreateJS suite) is an excellent webGL graphics/games library backed by big names like Microsoft and Adobe.

Seems to be best.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may have picked wrong tech. HTML5 Canvas is also 2D **but** it works on iOS and Android!

And do not forget to try first some high level game-specific library, or maybe ready to use game engine. This way it will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

[ChesterGL](https://github.com/funkaster/ChesterGL) Looks like a promising up-and-coming.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this sounds like a good candidate for Unity.